# Проблема при работе с Java кодом

Tags: java, android, cordova

Мне надо написать плагин для `Cordova` для работы по `Bluetooth`. Нашел работающий код на `Java` и теперь мне надо интегрировать его в свой плагин. Начал использовать код, вот пример того, что сейчас есть:

```
package com.moduscreate.plugin;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

public class ModusEcho extends CordovaPlugin {
  @Override
  // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChatService";

    // Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
    private static final String NAME_SECURE = "BluetoothChatSecure";
    private static final String NAME_INSECURE = "BluetoothChatInsecure";

    // Unique UUID for this application
    private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE =
            UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");

    // Member fields
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private AcceptThread mSecureAcceptThread;
    private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private int mState;
    private int mNewState;

    // Constants that indicate the current connection state
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

  public boolean execute(
    String action,
    JSONArray args,
    CallbackContext callbackContext
  ) throws JSONException {
    if ("echo".equals(action)) {
      echo(args.getString(0), callbackContext);
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  private void echo(
    String msg,
    CallbackContext callbackContext
  ) {
    if (msg == null || msg.length() == 0) {
      callbackContext.error("Empty message!");
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(
        webView.getContext(),
        msg,
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
      ).show();
      callbackContext.success(msg);
    }
  }
}
```

Запускаю на исполнение и получаю ошибку:

```
    /platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/moduscreate/plugin/ModusEcho.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
    private AcceptThread mSecureAcceptThread;
            ^
  symbol:   class AcceptThread
  location: class ModusEcho
/Users/taruk/App/BChat/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/moduscreate/plugin/ModusEcho.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
    private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;
            ^
  symbol:   class AcceptThread
  location: class ModusEcho
/Users/taruk/App/BChat/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/moduscreate/plugin/ModusEcho.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
            ^
  symbol:   class ConnectThread
  location: class ModusEcho
/Users/taruk/App/BChat/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/moduscreate/plugin/ModusEcho.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
            ^
  symbol:   class ConnectedThread
  location: class ModusEcho
/Users/taruk/App/BChat/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/moduscreate/plugin/ModusEcho.java:26: error: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
  @Override
  ^
5 errors
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Может кто подсказать, что я делаю не так? Готов даже заплатить, если кто то согласится на консультации.

Comment: я выложил задание на один ресурс, никто не откликнулся, вот и решил попробовать собственные силы. извините, если не по адресу обратился

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас непроимпортированы классы

```
AcceptThread
ConnectThread
ConnectedThread
```

добавьте их в секцию `import` с указанием полного имени